# Tem como rodar dois loops ao mesmo tempo no python?

Tags: python-3.x

Eu estava querendo fazer uma especie de jogo que você vai comprando algumas coisas que te ajudam a lucrar, e você teria uma quantia que você ganhava por segundo, mas eu nao sei se tem como eu rodar dois loops(um para fazer a interação com o jogador  e o outro para adicionar uma quantia de dinheiro ao jogador por segundo) no python, se alguem souber, pode me ajudar?

Comment: Você pode ter um único laço e embutir uma máquina de estado, no primeiro estado você interage com o jogador e no segundo cuida adiciona o dinheiro; fazendo rápido dará a sensação de que é simultâneo -- é como diversos jogos fazem.

Comment: É uma pergunta interessante porque levanta algumas questões do tipo - usar threads? Simular concorrência usando outras técnicas?

Comment: Você pode usar recursividade, um for dentro do outro ou duas funções, uma com cada for... São muitas possibilidades.

Answer (score -2):

Você pode utilizar threads. Seu uso permite que você paralelize tarefas em seu programa. Caso você utilize essa solução, se existir alguma variável que seja modificada por mais de uma thread, recomendo que crie um bloqueio. O motivo é que, sem um bloqueio, a variável pode assumir um valor diferente do desejado.

> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_multithreading.htm
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects

Answer (score -3):

O ideal é utilizar classes e funções dentro de heranças. Threads são uma opção porém é uma lógica que pode resultar muitos erros se você estiver no início. Antes de executar qualquer código, tente fazer a estrutura em herança das classes e funções. Para este caso, poderia ter uma classe "tempo" que teria funções sendo executadas com tempos diferentes